# How do I get the class of a parameterized type in Java without instantiating it?

Tags: java, class, generics, types, parameter-passing

So say need to pass in the class that represents LinkedList<Path>:
java.lang.Class<java.util.LinkedList<java.nio.file.Path>>

without creating one and then using .getClass() ?

FindBugs is bitching at me that this is the only reason I create the object, and the IDE is telling me I can't pass a value of a parameterized type.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean “pass in?” Are you making a linked list? Or is it a method param?

Comment: Can you show actual code so we can see what are you trying to do?

Comment: The basic answer is you can't. But this look like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please explain your goal.

Comment: Could you give a proper example ?

Comment: Use a a class constant: `LinkedList.class`.